# Datetime Format in Sql server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have field in sql table DateIn, in table date exists like '01/04/2012 00:00:00'. when i run query on query analyzer DateIn comes like '2012-04-01 00:00:00.000' i am passing date from text box like 'dd/mm/yyyy' format but not working. I have function where i am passing date variable Dim StrDate as DateTime from text box to query. Please guide me.

Comment: date time not filtering like i am calling records from 01/06/2012 to 26/06/2012, data coming of all dates in tables.

Comment: What is the data type of the `DateIn` column?

Comment: DateTime is the datatype

Answer (score 0):

If the column is `datetime` please stop thinking it is stored in some format like `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`. Date/time values are stored internally without any of this regional formatting applied - this is just the way Management Studio is presenting it to you. You should write queries using `yyyymmdd` for date literals, like:

```
SELECT <cols> 
FROM dbo.table 
WHERE DateIn >= '20120601'
AND DateIn < '20120626';
```

Anything else is prone to not work if a different user executes, if the regional settings on the machine change, or if you move your code to another server. Please see:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Also be sure you are using string delimiters. If you say:

```
WHERE DateIn > 01/06/2012
```

That is the same as:

```
WHERE DateIn > (1 divided by 6 divided by 2012)
```

Which yields, due to integer math:

```
WHERE DateIn > 0
```

In SQL Server, 0 as a date/time is `'1900-01-01'` - therefore this clause will return all non-NULL rows.